# How to convert KerasTensor to numpy array or TensorFlow EagerTensor?

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, opencv, keras

I have a KerasTensor object with shape (None, 128, 128, 1) that I need to pass to an OpenCV function. However, I'm having trouble converting the KerasTensor to either a numpy array or a TensorFlow EagerTensor that can be accepted by the function. Specifically, I want to convert the KerasTensor to a format that is compatible with OpenCV's input requirements. Any suggestions on how to achieve this conversion?

I tried using tensor.numpy() to convert the KerasTensor to a numpy array, but I got an AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Define the shape of the input tensor
input_shape = (128, 128, 1)

# Create an input tensor with the specified shape
input_tensor = keras.layers.Input(shape=input_shape)

# Create a model that uses the input tensor
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(32, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(input_tensor)
x = keras.layers.Conv2D(64, 3, activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
output_tensor = keras.layers.Conv2D(1, 3, activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

print(type(output_tensor)) # <class 'keras.engine.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>

# Convert the output tensor to a numpy array
print(type(output_tensor.numpy())) # AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'
print(type(tf.keras.backend.eval(output_tensor))) #AttributeError: 'KerasTensor' object has no attribute 'numpy'`
```

Comment: keras tensors usually are just a sort of placeholders when you build a model, thus can not be converted to numpy... please post the code

Comment: Pleas follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have edited the post and added a simplified example of what I want to do.